# b.createDocumentFragment is not a function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, twitter

I'm playing around with a function and getting

```
b.createDocumentFragment is not a function (jQuery)
```

My function is

```
function tweetCount(url) {  
    $.getJSON("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url="+url+"&callback=?", function(data) {
      count = data.count
      $(this).append(count);
   })
}
```

I've tried lots of different way but can't seem to find out why it doesn't like "append". "count" is a number and something like alert(count) works, but not append!

Any help?!
Alex

Comment: what is `$(this)`?? Try `alert(this)` to see if it's even defined. I'm guessing this function is not bound to an existing jquery context for you to call it that way...

Comment: @Alex javascript does semicolon insertion, but it is better to include them

Comment: $(this) is defined, alert(this) gives [object, Object] !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that `this` is referring to what you think it is. Change `$(this)` to an explicit reference to the DOM element you want.

Alternatively, you can define `this` by calling:

```
tweetCount.call($("#element"), url)
```

**Edit**

Try this:

```
$("span.tweetcount").each(function(){
    url = $(this).attr('title');
    tweetCount.call(this, url);
});
```

Or, to save space:

```
$("span.tweetcount").each(function(){
    tweetCount.call(this, $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

**Edit 2:**

Try replacing `tweetCount` with this:

```
function tweetCount(url) {  
    var that = this;
    $.getJSON("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url="+url+"&callback=?", function(data) {
        count = data.count;
        $(that).append(count);
})
```

Comment: The problem is I'm doing something like -  $("span.tweetcount").each(function(){
  url = $(this).attr('title')
  tweetCount(url)
 })

Comment: would that be - $(x).append(count); or x.append(count); in the function?

Comment: It's fine as it is: `$(this).append(count)`. Using `call` lets you adjust `this` to point to what you want it to.

Comment: Still gives me the same problem!

Comment: Can you verify that `data.count` is correct? What does `alert(data.count)` yield?

Comment: @AlexFox let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2332/discussion-between-simplecoder-and-alex-fox)